# How to convert .mat to image file

Tags: python, scipy

I'm trying to convert the SVHN format 2 (32x32 cropped images) dataset into a directory of images. Currently, when you download the format 2 of the SVHN images it is in a .mat format. How can I change this .mat format to give me all of the images in png or jpg format? I have loaded the images using SciPy but after that, I'm stuck. I know that SciPy creates a dictionary out of the .mat file containing two keys (X and Y). I know that X is image data and Y is their respective labels. How can I convert this dictionary to all of the cropped images?

```
import scipy.io

train_data = scipy.io.loadmat('train_32x32.mat')
```

Any help is appreciated, thank you!

Comment: What do you get from `train_data['X']`, i.e. accessing the `X` data?  My guess is that it is a `numpy` array.  What's it's shape and dtype?  Have you looked into using any Python image package?

Comment: I solved this by creating a numpy array out of the X and y keys! You were correct.

Comment: Hi @MicahMca!
Can you post the answer? I'm trying to do the same. Can you please post the source code to extract an png?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
import scipy.io

train_data = scipy.io.loadmat('train_32x32.mat', variable_names='X').get('X')
train_labels = scipy.io.loadmat('train_32x32.mat', variable_names='y').get('y')
test_data = scipy.io.loadmat('test_32x32.mat', variable_names='X').get('X')
test_labels = scipy.io.loadmat('test_32x32.mat', variable_names='y').get('y')
```

now if you print shape you will see ...

```
print(train_data.shape, train_labels.shape)
print(test_data.shape, test_labels.shape)
```

the results are:

(32, 32, 3, 73257) (73257, 1)

(32, 32, 3, 26032) (26032, 1)

i suggest to work with this shapes:

```
train_dataset = train_data.transpose((3,0,1,2))
train_label = train_labels[:,0]
test_dataset = test_data.transpose((3,0,1,2))
test_label = test_labels[:,0]

print(train_dataset.shape, train_label.shape)
print(test_dataset.shape, test_label.shape)
```

now the shapes are:

(73257, 32, 32, 3) (73257,)

(26032, 32, 32, 3) (26032,)